# Renderscript how to init a buffer from a 2d float array for an allocation

Tags: android, allocation, renderscript

I read the Android documentation about allocations and I also used them in few renderscripts. But there is something that still I couldn't understand.

If I create an allocation with **createTyped()** I create the structure but not the buffer, actually until now I used this method for input allocations and the buffer is then assigned when it does **ioReceive()**. 
To create an output allocation usually I use **createFromBitmap()** because this method also allocates the buffer. Otherwise to assign the buffer I can use **setSurface()**.

But now I need an output allocation for a 2D float array, how can initialize and assign the buffer for such allocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the allocation with createTyped() and then initialize it by calling copyFrom(myfloatarray) where myfloatarray is an array of float values in Java.

Comment: Thank you.
It's also worth mentioning that even if it is an output allocation the usage flag should not be set USAGE_IO_OUTPUT. Best thing to do is setting only Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT.